# Calling a templated functor in a class template

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to call the functor `operator()( int )` of a the class template `Foo` as shown below ([online version](http://rextester.com/RPO75528))

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename U>
    void operator()( int )
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo<char> foo;
    foo<bool>( 42 );
}
```

I'm getting the error message in gcc 4.9.3

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘bool’
  foo<bool>( 42 );
```

I'd prepend the functor with `template` if the member function wasn't a functor and was prefixed with `::`, `.`, or `->`. Without some help the compiler couldn't know how to parse this expression ; as a functor or an instantiation of an anonymous object of type `foo<int>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would work with;

```
foo.operator()<bool>( 42 );
```

Operators play best with deduced template argument types.

You don't give enough detail of the context in which this is used, as alternatives you could consider;

- making the call operator a member function and thus allow explicit template type arguments
- a tag dispatch mechanism
- accept the type `U` as an argument

For example;

```
template<typename U>
void operator()( int, U&& /*initial*/ )
{
  // use the initial value of U
}
// called as...

foo(42, true); // U is bool in your example
```

Or simply the member function;

```
template<typename U>
void my_func( int )
{
}
// called as...

foo.my_fun<bool>( 42 );
```

Comment: "Operators play best with deduced template argument types" -- worth remembering. I left out the `&&` though.

Comment: @Olumide. The `U&&` argument is used just with the idea that if the type was more complex that a primitive, a `std::move` could be used or the `U&&` can bind to a temporary as well. A simple `U` would also work just fine.

Comment: Is this problem still the case with `c++17`?

Comment: @ar2015 Not sure if the template deduction guides would make a difference, I haven't really had cause to use them much as yet. Or if they are usable with operators. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Answer (score 5):

Yes but it's ugly:

```
foo.operator()<bool>( 42 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you'd need to use `foo.operator()<bool>(42);` for this. `foo<bool>` is valid for things like C++14 variable templates, not template call operators.

What you could do is tag the type and pass that in as an argument to the call operator to deduce the right type:

```
//tag
template <typename T>
struct type{};

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename U>
    //deduction on the tagged type
    void operator()( type<U>, int )
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo<char> foo;
    foo( type<bool>{}, 42 );
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ pass tag
}
```

You could make this a bit nicer using C++14 variable templates for the tag:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_t{};

//variable template for nicer usage
template <typename T>
type_t<T> type;

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename U>
    void operator()( type_t<U>, int )
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo<char> foo;
    foo( type<bool>, 42 );
    //don't need {}^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the syntax gets more elaborate if the functor is itself a template. The below will fail:

```
template <typename Functor, typename ... Args>
void Foo (Functor & f)
{
    f.operator()<Args...>();
}

struct MyFunctor
{
    template <typename ...>
    void operator () () {}
};

int main ()
{
    MyFunctor f;
    Foo(f);
}
```

We instead must write:

```
f.template operator()<Args...>();
```